Correct Navigation Graph Approach to have both Buyer and Seller Functionality in a single app?
Is this way to have both functionality of a buyer and seller in single app correct? Tell me the best approach to declare navigation for both of them and also the whole navigation is wrapped in a bottomnavigation scaffold.
And I am using that scaffold to show bottom navigation bar at different screens.
@Composable
fun MasterNavigation (
    navController: NavHostController,
    currentUser:FirebaseUser?,
    userType: UserType?,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val currentuser = Firebase.auth.currentUser

    var startDestination = "Auth_Graph"
    if(currentuser !=null){
//                    startDestination = "App_Navigation"
        if(userType == UserType.CUSTOMER){
            startDestination = "Buyer_App_Navigation"
        }
        else if(userType == UserType.PROVIDER){
            startDestination = "App_Navigation"
        }
        else{
            startDestination = "App_Navigation"
        }

//        startDestination = "test"
    }

    NavHost(navController = navController,startDestination = startDestination ){

        composable("test"){
            LoginScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        navigation(route= "Auth_Graph",startDestination = "Login_Screen"){
            composable("Login_Screen"){
                LoginScreen(navController)
            }
            composable("Register_Screen"){
                RegisterScreen(navController)
            }
        }
        navigation(route = "App_Navigation",startDestination = "Home_Screen" ){
            composable("Home_Screen"){
//            AddProductScreen()
                HomeScreen(sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel,navController)

            }
            composable("Chat_Screen"){
                ChatScreen()
            }
            composable("Market_Price_Screen"){
                MarketPriceScreen()
            }
            composable("Add_Product_Screen"){
                AddProductScreen()
            }
            composable("Profile_Screen"){
                ProfileScreen(navController = navController)
            }
            navigation(route="Edit_Product",startDestination = "Edit_Product_Screen"){
                composable("Edit_Product_Screen"){
                    EditProductScreen(navController,sharedViewModel)
                }
            }

        }
        navigation(route = "Buyer_App_Navigation",startDestination = "Buyer_Home_Screen"){
            composable("Buyer_Home_Screen"){
                BuyerHomeScreen(navController)
            }
            composable("Chat_Screen"){
                ChatScreen()
            }
            composable("Market_Price_Screen"){
                MarketPriceScreen()
            }

            composable("Profile_Screen"){
                ProfileScreen(navController = navController)
            }
            navigation(route="Product_Detail",startDestination = "Product_Detail_Screen"){
                composable("Product_Detail_Screen"){
                    ProductDetailScreen(navController,sharedViewModel)
                }
            }


        }

    }

}


You started making application without proper user experience analyzing. Draw your mockup in paper, and see how your app should look like in every use case. From your drawings, you can see which button should trigger navController.navigate(specifiedRoute).

@anhtuannd thank you for that, as i want to have both the buyer and seller functionality how a navgraph should look like, i am talking about how to design a ideal navgraph in this situation

Usually when there are many navigation (similar to your case when user has both BUY and SELL role), we can think about Navigation Drawer instead of Bottom Bar.
